# Python inline syntax questions

Tags: python, syntax

I can't seem to find a valid source that will tell me what the following does and I'm trying to learn about different python techniques, could anyone explain these lines of code, and possibly show their equivalent?

```
shortest_path = {initial: (None, 0)}

next_destinations = {node: shortest_paths[node] for node in shortest_paths if node not in visited}

current_node = min(next_destinations, key=lambda k: next_destinations[k][1])
```

For reference a node is a being made as a string.

Comment: Which line don't you understand? There are loads of Python tutorials on the web, this question is too broad unless you specify one particular concept/technique you don't understand. ("Inline syntax" doesn't really mean anything.)

Comment: @Joe if your questions regarding the second line, keep this new term in your head: _comprehensions_.

Comment: I don't understand the bracket notation with things such {initial: (None, 0)}

Comment: @Joe: that's a dictionary, look up in the internet for how python dictionaries work.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS the 2nd line only contains a new line character ;)

Comment: @Chris_Rands sneaky, but you get what I mean. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Line 1**

```
shortest_path = {initial: (None, 0)}
```

Created a dictionary. 1 key: `initial`. Its value: `(None, 0)` which is a tuple with `None` and `0` (zero).

**Line 2**

```
next_destinations = {node: shortest_paths[node] for node in shortest_paths if node not in visited}
```

dictionary comprehention. maps beteen `node` to `shortest_paths[node]`. It does it `for` each `node in shortest_paths` and does it only `if node not in visited`

Output of this line is a dict

**Line 3**

```
current_node = min(next_destinations, key=lambda k: next_destinations[k][1])
```

tries to find a minimum value and assign it to`current_node`. Min on what? On `next_destinations`. How to know how to deside? by the `key` which is function given `k`, check `next_destinations[k][1]`.